# How do I make the game end when everybody is dead on a separate team?

Tags: rec-room

I was making a game in Rec Room and when I tested it I realised that everybody was dead and the game didn't end. I tried it with the role-changed chip but I didn't see the "Eliminated" role as an option and I don't know how to give people a role when the game starts, so that wasn't an option either.

Info about the game:
The game is a Freezetag game where there is 1 tagger and the rest are runners.